# How do I approach this python test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a function inside a class, that calls other functions and does some stuff until it obtains two variables, **A** and **B**:

```
Class NumberLogic:
    def compare():
    #do stuff_
    A=#do stuff__
    B=#do stuff___
    if A<B:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

I would like to test this function compare() but give values directly from A and B so only the if condition is tested, I am not sure if this is possible and the rest of the code can be mocked so when I call someting like

```
assert 1 == NumberLogic.compare()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
Class NumberLogic:
    def compare(self):
        A = self._get_A()
        B = self._get_B()
        return self._compare(A, B)

    def _get_A(self):
        # do stuff
        return A

    def _get_B(self):
        # do stuff
        return B

    def _compare(self, A, B):
        if A<B:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
```

This way you can write your code to check only the `_compare`

Note: Starting a function with an underscore signifies it's an internal method only used by the function itself.

You could also write:

```
def _compare(self, A, B):
    if A<B:
        return 1
    return 2
```

Which is the same thing